# Delete the blank line CHAR(10) in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

As the above picture, I need to delete that blank line. 
I tried all the below formulas, but none of it works correctly. 
`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")`  
`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(13))`  
`=CLEAN(A1)`

"Damage noted at of FAR. Inspect area (UT or LRUT)

Update 5th Oct 2012: Confirmed equipment redunant
Update 30th May13:  Close Out inspection revealed"

**Note**: I am using Office 2016

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))` maybe?

Comment: I copied the data rom your post and `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")` worked for me. Seems like there is some other character. May I see a sample file?

Comment: Yes both `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))` & `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")` on my end as well. Can you try finding the offending character using `=CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))`

Comment: @JvdV , I tried your suggestion.and it works correctly

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya ,I tried `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))` and it works perfectly, But `=CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))` didn't work, because my office version is 2016

Comment: @Leedo no worries. Here you go with alternative approach which will work with your version of `Excel`, `=CODE(MID(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1))),1))` note that it is possible to use `INDIRECT()` function in place of `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A1)))` but we don't suggest as it is volatile in nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comments, just delete the double newline-char, and replace it with a single one:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't top JvdV's answer, but this would deal with any number of consecutive line breaks:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^"),CHAR(10)," "))," ",CHAR(10)),"^"," ")`

Where I first replace al spaces with a character we expect not to be in the string (I took `^`).
Then we replace `CHAR(10)` with space and perform `TRIM`, so any multiple of spaces becomes a single space.
Then we revert the characters back to what they where. Spaces to line breaks and `^` to space.

Or better:
Do JvdV's logic twice to deal with uneven count of multiple line breaks:

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10)),CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),CHAR(10))`

And in Office 365: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,(TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(10),,1)))`